# CarRacing-v0 have to render when training?

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-gym, dqn

the game windows always jump out on both macos and colab, and throw the error "pyglet.canvas.xlib.NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"
"

How to close the game windows when training?